# Interview stumper: friends of friends of friends

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, scalability

Suppose you have a social network with a billion users. On each user's page, you want to display the number of that users friends, friends of friends, and so on, out to five degrees. Friendships are reciprocal. The counts don't need to update right away, but they should be precise.

I read up on graphs, but I didn't find anything that suggested a scalable approach to this problem. Anything I could think of would take way too much time, way too much space, or both. This is driving me nuts!

Comment: use breadth first search. BFS guarantees that all friends of degree 1 are searched before degree 2, and all friends of degree 2 are searched before degree 3, and so on. As you visit each undiscovered friend, mark it as discovered, and increment count by one. Have a variable to track the degree of search. Stop when all friends of degree 5 have been visited.

Comment: @JasonL- In a large social network, this will explore such a huge number of nodes that it would be prohibitively expensive.

Comment: Could this be done sensibly with one initially expensive full-graph search (maybe using matrix stuff instead of BFS), and then whenever connections or users are added or deleted, you go "my k-th degree friends are the union over all (k-1)-th degree friends of my first-degree friends"? If you only want people to be listed for the smallest k that applies to them, this would obviously mean some cleanup after that set operation.

Comment: I wonder about how feasible this task is. Suppose that "6 degrees of separation" is not far off, this would suggest that for five degrees, you could get a two digit percentage of the whole graph as your fifth degree friends. How would you manage that volume of information for each of the billion users? Even just assigning each user a number as their ID and using bitvectors to store the information, that would require more than 100 MB just to store the fifth degree friends, giving us a requirement of roughly 100 Petabytes of information to store the fifth degree friends of all 1 billion users.

Comment: @G.Bach I think one key is to not calculate the friends for every home page, only for the ones that are currently displayed.

Comment: Have I forgotten everything about graph algorithms? What is so slow about the BFS? For a graph this sparse its runtime is `O(n)`. Even better, we get to stop when we visit an unvisited node from a current node with `degreeOfSeparation == 5` (the same as Jason L suggested, except I don't understand how he keeps track of the degrees of separation). I don't have any hard figures, but I can't imagine the subgraph of paths of length <= 5 is more than a few million. A BFS over a few million nodes is pretty fast... isn't it? I'm even more confused as to why the matrix approach would be faster.

Answer (score 4):

One interesting approach is to translate the friend graph into an adjacency matrix, and then raise the matrix to the 5th power. This gives you an adjacency matrix containing counts of the number of paths-of-length-5 between each node.

Note that you'll want a matrix multiplication algorithm that can take advantage of sparse matrices, since the friends adjacency matrix is likely to be sparse for the first couple levels. Lucky for you, people have a done a lot of work on how to multiply huge matrices (especially sparse ones) efficiently.

Here's a [video where Twitter's Oscar Boykin mentions this approach](http://youtu.be/JF-ttZyNa84?t=14m54s) for computing followers of followers at Twitter.

Comment: Will this over-count friends-of-friends? Suppose A has friends B and C, both of whom are friends of D. A has two friends, but one friend-of-friends.

Comment: Ah, to avoid that issue you need to reduce every non-zero matrix entry to one after each multiplication.

Comment: When you say "a naive breadth-first-search would take O(n^3) just for friends-of-friends", is n the size of the graph?

Comment: Yes, although obviously that doesn't apply if the graph is super-sparse.

Comment: I think any reasonable approach to this has to assume a super-sparse graph. The only thing I don't like about this is that it does the whole calculation in one gulp. BFS can be run on demand when a home page needs to be displayed.

Comment: how do you come up with `O(n^3)`? even a naive bfs shouldn't require more than `O(E) = O(n^2)` at max. compare that with strassen's `O(n^2.8)` and coppersmith-winograd's `O(n^2.38)`.

Comment: @collapsar One factor of n for iterating over each node-to-compute-the-statistic-for. One factor of n for the first level of the search (this is where sparsity would help). One factor of n for the second  level of the search (again, sparsity).

Comment: @Strilanc You can do all levels in one BFS pass.

Comment: @G.Bach How? You need to keep track of overlaps to avoid double-counting, and that will be different for each starting node.

Comment: @strilanc: ok, so you set `n` to the average fanout instead of the total number of network users ?

Comment: @collapsar Right. Ultimately, the last fanout (5th level) is likely to cover a significant proportion of the network. I think the asymptotic complexity, when you go out that many levels and six-degrees-of-separation applies, will be O(N*E*log(n)) = O(N*N*F*log(N)). That should indeed be better than the matrix's O(MatrixMul(N)) ~= O(N^2.38) for large values of N.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the problem really comes down to how we hash/track 1 Billion users as we are counting the friends at each level. (Note that we only need to count them, NOT store them)

If we assume that for each person, their friend and the friends of their friends are of very small order (say <1000 and <100,000) it seems practical to keep these stored in database tables for each user. It only requires two manageable passes of the entire database and then straight-forward additions to the tables when a "new" relationship is created.

If we have 1st and 2nd degree friend stored in a users tables we can leverage those to extend as far as we need to -

EG: to COUNT 3rd degree friend we need to hash and track the 1st degree friends of all the 2nd degree friends. (for 4th degree you do all 2nd's of Seconds, for higher degrees you create the  4th and then extend appropriately to 5th or 6th).

So, at that point (5th and 6th degree friends) you are starting to approach 1 Billion as the number of people that you need to track, hash and count.

I'm thinking that the problem then becomes, what is the most efficient way to has 1 billion record-ID's as you "count" the friends in the higher order relationships.

How you do that, I don't know - any thoughts?